# Is it impossible to mitigate the Correlation Attack if I use Tor to access a website hosted in my home country?

Tags: private

I think the question is already clear enough. So, just to make it clearer, it can be interpreted as:

Is it true that my government will always be able to correlate me with the website which is also located in my country even when I use Tor.

Because it is widely known that AS-level adversary can deanonymize Tor user if it locates at both ends of the Tor anonymous path. And since I am using Tor to access a website located in my home country, my government definitely can monitor both Client<->Guard and Exit<->Website. As a result, when it comes to visiting a website hosted in my home country, it is useless to use Tor to hide my identity, isn't it?

Regards,

Comment: In theory, yes. In practise, unknown. While it's likely there will *always* be problems with onion routing (see the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AttacksOnOnionRouting)), there are attempts to thwart *specific* attacks (e.g. [WTF-Pad](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00524.pdf)) but there are various other methods. It may not be true that your adversary is well funded, well placed, and well informed enough to perform the attacks and most only provide a probability of accurate detection, however it is true that they are a general weakness with *low-latency* anonymity networks.